# Laragon 400 Bad Request Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laragon

just now i install laragon and getting 400 bad request, i have no idea how to fix.
Laragon full 2.2.2 php-7.1.1

Access log --

```
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Apr/2017:15:42:44 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 347  
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Apr/2017:15:42:44 +0300] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 400 347
```

Error log --

```
Apache server interrupted...  
[Mon Apr 03 15:42:38.008826 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11704:tid 580]  AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.    
[Mon Apr 03 15:42:42.686208 2017] [core:warn] [pid 16048:tid 548] AH00098: pid  
  file C:/laragon/bin/apache/httpd-2.4.25-win32-VC14/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?  
[Mon Apr 03 15:42:42.827314 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 16048:tid 548] AH00455: Apache/2.4.25 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2k PHP/7.1.1 configured -- resuming normal operations  
[Mon Apr 03 15:42:42.827314 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 16048:tid 548] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Dec 17 2016 10:42:52  
[Mon Apr 03 15:42:42.827314 2017] [core:notice] [pid 16048:tid 548] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\laragon\\bin\\apache\\httpd-2.4.25-win32-VC14\\bin\\httpd -d C:/laragon/bin/apache/httpd-2.4.25-win32-VC14'  
[Mon Apr 03 15:42:42.829314 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 16048:tid 548] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 14292  
[Mon Apr 03 15:42:44.474536 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 14292:tid 612] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
```

Comment: There's nothing in the error log that corresponds to the requests in the access log. You probably should check the error logs of laravel

Comment: I dont have any .log file
p.s. i cloned project from a github.

Comment: The log you need to check is located at `/storage/logs/`

Comment: @NicklasKevinFrank empty, only .gitignore

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your `ServerName` contains only alphanumerical characters.

Eg: `http://dummy_domain.local` produces `400 Bad Request` (with Apache 2.4) while `http://dummy-domain.local` works as expected.